# google app engine PHP ebay search API return null

Tags: php, google-app-engine, xmlhttprequest

I am making an eBay search API call `findItemsByKeywords` in php on google app engine. It is working locally, not on the GAE. This is how I make the call

```
$resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);
```

I checked the hosting provide has enabled PHP to open URLs as files `ini_get('allow_url_fopen')` returns 1.

I am getting null in $resp only when running on GAE.

***Edit:***

here is the content in the GAE error log.

```
2014-06-12 16:21:50 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=10080', '--admin_port=8002', 'C:\\app_engine\\invApp']"
INFO     2014-06-12 16:21:53,055 devappserver2.py:716] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2014-06-12 16:21:53,076 api_server.py:378] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2014-06-12 16:21:53,099 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http://localhost:16086
INFO     2014-06-12 16:21:53,107 dispatcher.py:182] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:10080
INFO     2014-06-12 16:21:53,111 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8002
INFO     2014-06-12 16:22:01,536 module.py:639] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1637
INFO     2014-06-12 16:22:01,566 module.py:639] default: "GET /static/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 206
INFO     2014-06-12 16:22:01,568 module.py:639] default: "GET /static/script.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
ERROR    2014-06-12 16:22:01,566 module.py:714] Request to '/static/main.css' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 710, in _handle_request
    return handler.handle(match, environ, wrapped_start_response)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\static_files_handler.py", line 369, in handle
    return self._handle_path(full_path, environ, start_response)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\static_files_handler.py", line 182, in _handle_path
    start_response('200 OK', headers)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 640, in wrapped_start_response
    return start_response(status, response_headers, exc_info)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2155, in start_response
    raise TypeError("WSGI response header value %r is not of type str." % v)
TypeError: WSGI response header value u'text/css' is not of type str.
INFO     2014-06-12 16:22:01,571 module.py:639] default: "GET /static/main.css HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2014-06-12 16:22:11,984 module.py:639] default: "GET /api.php?target=ebay&searchClause=cake|3|4|true HTTP/1.1" 200 940
```

***Edit:***

I found a solution.
I have to use `file_get_contents` and then if successful, do `simplexml_load_string`.
For some reason GAE does not let me use `simplexml_load_file`.

This is the code that works.

```
$resp = file_get_contents($apicall);
if($resp){
    $result = simplexml_load_string($resp);       
}

exit(json_encode($result));
```

Comment: Is there a way to view the error logs on GAE?

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the error log. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Disabled_functions "You must also call libxml_disable_entity_loader(false) somewhere in your application's startup script to enable loading of external XML entities."